# "Match" not returning results

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to look for any match from column A in column D, then if so do something else.

Having problems getting my match to work and not sure why.

I have this forumla in column C.

=IFERROR(IF(MATCH("|"&A2&"|",D$1:D$6,0),"True","False"),"Error")

[image]

Not sure if it matters but my values in column A and D are from other formulas in those cells.

Comment: Try `... MATCH("*|"&A2&"|*", ...`

Comment: It might be better to return actual Boolean values and an actual error, ie `=IFERROR(IF(MATCH("*|"&A2&"|*",D$1:D$6,0),True,False),Na())`

Comment: @JvdV Sir, i think it should be reverse, `=COUNTIF(D$1:D$6,"*|"&A2&"|*")>0` because i tried the one which you shared it says there is a problem in the formula, as may be the criteria considered as a range while the range as criteria

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya correct. I had shared it from my phone without an attempt. Mixed up parameters.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up going with this.

```
=ISNUMBER(MATCH("*|"&A2&"|*",D$1:D$6,0))
```

Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Just as a variant you can use find():

[image]

Then use iferror() and if() to control what you need for the results.

So added more of your data:
[image]